# Include .NET-Runetime into c#/.NET App

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I would like to create a program in c#/Winforms which can run on all windows devices from xp up to 10. To do so, every computer must at least have .NET 2 installed (I don't need something else).

However, is there a way that my .NET takes the whole Framework with it, so it can run standalone? Even if the user has not installed the .NET 5 Framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by the installer of your app. Here is an example with [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html).

You will have two options: pull .NET from the Internet or bundle it into your installer for offline mode.

Comment: I don't want to have an installer. I need something more like:
User gets .EXE, clicks it and it works fine. That should be all...

Comment: Installer can be in a form of .exe file. I am not aware of other approaches.

Comment: No, i mean there should not be an installer at all. The given .EXE itself has to be the program!